# I want to hide a div, like a footer when my website is running outside of the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser

I want to hide a div, like a footer when my website is running outside of the browser(like when I redirect the website from a mobile app using react-native web view) and still show when using any browser. How can I implement it using javascript in my website code?

Comment: any image of what you wnna achieve or GIF